How to build a "complete" email from Contacts
When I want to send an email to one of my contacts, let's say:
Steve Jobs
work    steve.jobs@apple.com

from the Contacts application, it does only fill the To: field as follows:
 <steve.jobs@apple.com>

which is not a complete email. The syntactally complete form is:
 Steve Jobs <steve.jobs@apple.com>

Today a lot of Mail server quickly classify an incomplete recipient email
as a symptom of SPAM.
Then I would like to use only complete emails.
I didn't find an easy way to get or copy a complete email from Contacts.
I tried ^+click and ^+⌥+click on any email field with no success.
I found an heavy method to get a complete email for a contact, I just copy back
first and lastname in the email field and add chevrons around the fixed part as in:
work    Steve Jobs <steve.jobs@apple.com>

But this method doesn't scale for an address book of 1000 entries.
Is there any better receipe to get or copy automatically a complete email from Contacts?
Is there any way to extract from the command line (ex.: grep, awk, sed, perl… ) from the Contacts database the 3 fields necessary to compose a syntactically complete email:
$first" "$last" <"$work">"


Instead of copying from contacts, start typing the name and use auto-complete. It will fill in the email.

@Barmar let's say I am writing a text document with vi, how may I use this "auto-complete" function to write a list of complete emails?

I was talking about using it in the To or Cc fields when sending email.

Within for example Mail, then the To: or Cc: fields are incomplete emails. This is the beginning of the problem I'd like to solve. The number of professionnal mail servers which reject incomplete email is increasing, because it is the signature of automatic attacks. Real humans tend to use complete email. This is a kind of cheap reverse Turing test.
